# Benefits and trade offs for improving text search on small data in PostgreSQL

Tags: performance, postgresql, search, text

- I have 4 text columns of interest.
- Each column is up to about 100 characters.
- The text in 3 of the columns is mostly Latin words. (The data is a biological catalog, and these are names of things.)
- The data is currently about 500 rows. I don't expect this to grow beyond 1000.
- A small number of users (under 10) will have editing privileges to add, update, and delete data. I do not expect these users to put a heavy load on the database.

So all this suggests a pretty small data set to consider.

I need to perform a search on all 4 columns for rows where at least 1 column contains the search text (case insensitive). The query will be issued (and the results served) via a web application. I'm a bit lost about how to approach it.

PostgreSQL offers a few options for improving text searching speed. The possible options built into PostgreSQL I've been considering are

1. Don't try to index this at all. Just use `ILIKE`, `LIKE` on `lower`, or similar. (Without an index?)
2. Index with pg_trgm to improve search speed. I would assume that I would need to index the concatenation somehow.
3. Full text searching. I assume this would involve concatenating for the index also.

Unfortunately, I'm not really familiar with the expected performance of any of these or the benefits and trades off, so it's hard to know what things I should try first and what things I shouldn't even consider. Some things I have read suggest that doing the indexing for 2 and 3 is pretty slow, which conflicts with the fact that I'll be having occasional modifications going on. And the mixed language makes full text search seem unattractive since it appears to be language based, unless it can handle multiple languages simultaneously. Would I expect that for data this small, a simple `ILIKE` or maybe a `LIKE` on `lower` is probably fast enough? Or maybe the indexing is fast enough for the low load of modifications on data this small? Would I be better off looking for something outside the database?

Granted, I would have to actually benchmark all these to really know for sure what's fastest, but unfortunately, I don't have much time for this project. So what are the benefits and trade offs of these methods? What of these options are not appropriate for solving this type of problem? What are some other types of solutions (including potentially outside the database) worth considering?

(I suppose I might find some kind of beginner's tutorial on text searching in PG useful, but my searches turn up Full Text Search for the most part, which I don't even know if it's useful for me.)

I'm on PG 9.2.4, so any goodies pre-9.3 are an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: I've expanded this answer into [a detailed blog post](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/text-search-strategies-in-postgresql/).

Rather than focusing purely on speed, please consider search semantics first. Define your requirements.

For example, do users need to be able to differentiate based on the *order* of terms? Should

```
radiata pinus
```

find:

```
pinus radiata
```

? Does the same rule apply to words within a column as between columns?

Are spaces always word separators, or are spaces within a column part of the search term?

Do you need wildcards? If so, do you need only left-anchored wildcards (think `staph%`) or do you need right-anchored or infix wildcards too (`%ccus`, `p%s`)? Only `pg_tgrm` will help you with infix wildcards. Suffix wildcards can be handled by an index on the `reverse()` of a word, but that gets clumsy quickly so in practice `pg_tgrm` is the best option there.

If you're mostly searching for discrete words and word-order isn't important, Pg's full-text search with `to_tsvector` and `to_tsquery` will be desirable. It supports left-anchored wildcard searches, weighting, categories, etc.

If you're mostly doing prefix searches of discrete columns then simple `LIKE` queries on a regular b-tree index per column will be the way to go.

So. Figure out what you need, *then* how to do it. Your current uncertainty probably stems partly from not really knowing quite what you want.

Comment: Also from not having a good grasp of what I'm doing when it comes to searches yet. ;) Thanks. This will help me ask good questions.

Comment: @jpmc26 In this case, it should also help you pick. Knowing what you need will help you exclude options. You've given me a good blog post idea, though.

Comment: When you write this blog post, please, please provide a link to it here. It would be greatly appreciated. Even if it's too late to help on this project, it would certainly help in the future.

Comment: Extra: for the latin-based names it will be benificial to turn off stemming completely. (or maybe create rules for scientific latin, but IMO an empty set would be preferrable)

Comment: @joop Yes, good point, if using tsearch the `simple` dictionary would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

For a 1000 rows, I would guess that `LIKE` together with `lower()` should be fast enough. After a couple of queries the table will most probably be completely cached.

Regarding the indexing using pg_trgm: you are talking about "occasional" updates/inserts to the table. I would think that the additional costs of using a trigram index would only show up when you update/insert that table **a lot** - like several times a second.

If "occasional" only means several times an hour (or even less), then I doubt you'd see the difference in real live. I think somewhere in Depesz's blob there was also an article that compared the insert speed with and without a trigram index, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I would expect updates every few minutes at most. Perhaps the occasional two people working at once and click Submit at the same time. Thank you.