# Hstore vs many-to-many relationship search performance

Tags: postgresql, hstore, postgresql-performance

Completely hypothetical question to compare performance of hstore is postgress
Let's say each user has a  list of followers. There are 2 way to implement it

1. Many-to-Many relationship with  a 'follower' table ( user_id, follower_id )
2. An hstore column where the values are the ids of the followers. (with a GiST index)

If I want to find all the users that follow a certain user, which version would perform faster?

1. `SELECT follower_id from follower where user_id = '1234'`
2. `SELECT user_id from user where (data @> 'followers=>'1234')`

In real life, for option b we would probably also maintain a list of all users the user follows - for the sake of the question let's assume we don't do that.

Comment: Create dummy data. Test it. Compare.

Comment: I know this isn't what you're hoping to hear, but make sure you consider your other data needs before performance. For example, if `follower_id` in your example must be a `user_id` in the user table, then you would get better enforcement of data integrity by using a bridge table that relates rows in the user table. Performance is only something you can consider once you're sure a potential solution actually meets your correctness and functional needs. ([I learned this lesson myself.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438996/))